# Glimpse causes 500 error on images and CSS

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, glimpse

I'm installing Glimpse on a .NET 4.6 project, but when I install the [Asp.Net package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Glimpse.AspNet) from NuGet all CSS and images throw a 500 error. I verified that the specific package is the [Asp.Net package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Glimpse.AspNet), I installed one at a time until the error was thrown.

The specific error is:

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' /
with unique key attribute 'name' set to 'Glimpse
```

The line causing the error is below, specifically the `<add>` element.

```
<handlers>
    <add name="Glimpse" path="glimpse.axd" verb="GET" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpHandler, Glimpse.AspNet" preCondition="integratedMode" />
</handlers>
```

How can I fix this problem so I can properly use Glimpse? I'm on Visual Studio 2015, IIS Express 10, .NET 4.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple things to check:

Since this line is in a web.config, have you checked all web.configs for this value?  Could be that multiple got put in spread across your project.

Second, you could try doing a remove

```
<remove name="Glimpse">
```

before the add statement and see if that clears it up.   Could be that Glimpse is added somewhere else on the system.

Comment: Perfect, adding the `<remove>` element was exactly it. I have two web projects that use separate directories, it seems like adding glimpse to the non-root one caused the issue. I kept it installed because I want to use glimpse on that directory, but adding `<remove>` fixed it. Thank you!